# How can I debug my docker with PHPStorm

Tags: docker

I had search a lot, and I try a lot. My question is very simple "How can I debug my docker with PHPStorm.

This is my **docker-compose.yml**, the `remote-host` ip is docker0's ip.

```
nginx:
  build: ./nginx/
  ports:
    - 80:80
  links:
    - php
  volumes_from:
    - app

php:
  build: ./php/
  expose:
    - 9000
  links:
    - mysql
  volumes_from:
    - app
  environment:
    XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.17.0.1"

app:
  image: php:5.6-fpm
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
  command: "true"

mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
      - data
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
      MYSQL_DATABASE: project
      MYSQL_USER: project
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: project

data:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
      - /var/lib/mysql
  command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
  image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
  ports:
    - 8080:8080
  links:
    - mysql
  environment:
    PMA_HOST: mysql
```

This is my php container Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

I run this commnad

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
```

And this is my PHPStorm setting

[image]

It's not work for me, I'm missing something? Thanks your help.

Comment: Maybe try with port 9000 instead of 80 in your PHPStorm setting, leaving nginx out for now. Also, `remote-host` might need to be the IP of your host machine, not `docker0`.

Comment: my host ip use `127.0.0.1` is right?

Comment: No, not `127.0.0.1`. Actually, `172.17.0.1` should work. What happened if you add `xdebug.remote_connect_back=On` to your `xdebug.ini`?

Comment: I fix it, I modify dockerfile, `FROM php:5.6-fpm
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql

RUN yes | pecl install xdebug \
    && echo "zend_extension=$(find /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/ -name xdebug.so)" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_enable=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini \
    && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=off" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_connect_back=on" >> /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini`

Comment: I think you can use this as this question answer. Thanks your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in your compose YAML and Dockerfile looks correct. Try add `xdebug.remote_connect_back=On` to your `xdebug.ini` file. In addition, for debugging purposes, try use port 80 in your PHPStorm setting instead of port 9000 (leaving out nginx for now).

Also, make sure `172.17.0.1` is reachable from within your container (which it usually is). One way to be sure is to run `/sbin/ip route|awk '/default/ { print $3 }'` in your container. It should return `172.17.0.1`.

Comment: Hi, Can I ask you a question, recently I install docker for mac beta, and now I open the website is `127.0.0.1`, but I try to run this command on my php container. the ip is same, but xdebug isn't work for me. I have no idea.

Comment: Try change `XDEBUG_CONFIG: "remote_host=172.17.0.1"` to use 127.0.0.1.